# How to fix Execution failed: TypeError: Can not read property "0" from undefined?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where some rows have pair values (in the first and in the 5th column) ​​that are always together (eg, identification person values​​) and values ​​that do not repeat (values related to some sort of event). I'm thinking about the most efficient way to automatically insert the second value when the user types the first value in the row. (the sheet contains thousands of lines and I wonder if it would be efficient).
But when I run my code:

```
var columnPredicted = getColumnNrByName(activeSheet, 'MY_COLUMN')+1;
var activeCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
var givenValueCell = activeSheet.getRange(activeRow, 1);
var givenValue = activeCell.getValue();
var predictedCell = activeSheet.getRange(activeRow, columnPredicted);  
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow()-1;
var input = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, columnPredicted).getValues();
Logger.log("input = " + input);
for(var j=input.length; j>0; j--){
     Logger.log("input = " + input[j][0]);          
        if (input[j][0] == givenValue) {
            predictedCell.setValue(input[i][0]);
            break;
        }
```

}

I got a message error saying that `Execution failed: TypeError: Can not read property "0" from undefined.` in the line `Logger.log("input = " + input[j][0])`. (the same happens in the line `if (input[j][0] == givenValue) {`. But the command `Logger.log("input = " + input);` shows the expected result. How to fix it?

Comment: `getValues()` returns a two dimensional array of values.  You are using a letter for the first dimension.  What do you get if you use: `input[0][0]` or `input[1][0]`?

Comment: Hi, @SandyGood, in both case I get the same error message. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I'd check the values in the variables, `columnPredicted` and `lastRow`.  `Logger.log('columnPredicted: ' + columnPredicted);  You'll need to start from the top, and check every line of code for what it's actually returning.  It seems like, for some reason, `input` is not being assigned what you expect.

Comment: In the execution transcript I got `Logger.log([predictedCell = Range, []])` and `Logger.log([columnPredicted = 5, []])`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var j=input.length; j>0; j--){
```

An array will be `[0..(length-1)]`, so there is no element `[length]`. Try this instead:

```
for(var j=input.length-1; j>0; j--){
                      ^^
```